# VS 2017 Xamarin.Froms The namespace 'x' already contains a definition for 'y'

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

With VS 2017 release I have created a new **Xamarin.Forms** Blank App (PCL) name App5.
Right click on App5(Portable) Add -> New Item... and choose "Forms MasterDetail Page Xaml" and default for Name "Page1.xaml" and hit Add.

Trying to Build the project and two errors are raising:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0101 The namespace 'App5' already contains a definition for 'Page1'
>   App5 C:\Xamarin Projects\App5\App5\App5\obj\Debug\App5.Page1.xaml.g.cs
>   17 Active
>
> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>       Error The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'App5, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>       File name: 'App5.dll'
>       at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>       at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
>       at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName)
>       at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String
>   fileName)
>       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res, ICollection1 jars, ICollection1 resolvedResourceDirectories,
>   ICollection1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection1
>   resolvedEnvironments)
>       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
>       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() App5.Android

Thanks in advance for any help,
AG